# Can I make my software go back to Google Chrome?

Tags: software-center, google-chrome

I want to download League of Legends on my new laptop but I bought a Chromebook without knowing League doesn't run on Google Chrome. I want to download Ubuntu so I can run windows software to download League but I want to know if there is a way I can return to my Google Chrome software easily at anytime before I change my laptop to run Windows.

Comment: You first say you want to run ubuntu and finally say you want to run Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [How to Easily Install Ubuntu on Chromebook with Crouton](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/795730-how-to-easily-install-ubuntu-on-chromebook-with-crouton) .

Personally I feel that you should get `XFCE`, as its lighter, unlike `Unity` and `KDE`.